# prometheus metric type for representing http status codes

Tags: python, devops, prometheus

I am sending get requests to some APIS for every interval of times to check whether the API is live or not based on http status code.I want to export these status code to prometheus so that I can visualise in Grafana and send some triggers based on status codes. Can anyone suggest which prometheus metric type is suitable for representing these http request codes

Comment: Did you consider using Blackbox Exporter (https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter)?

Answer (score 0):

I used blackbox-exporter and this exporter can be chack in many ways (like http_request or status code and etc)

it's very easily to use

first step u install blackbox-exporter and prometheus

then config blackbox-exporter and activate status-code (default is activated)

then in your Prometheus config u must add a job and define your target like this

```
  - job_name: node2-ping
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [icmp]
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 4.2.2.4     
        - 8.8.8.8
```

it can be checked this IP and send data into your Prometheus

Answer (score 0):

I found this page while looking for the answer to the same question but I think I figured it out. I would use a counter for the http responses and then add a label, such as status_code, that contains the value of the status code. You can then filter it such as `http_response{status_code="200"}`. I hope that works.